# jQuery and theme not working in stand alone page

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

I'm playing around with the jQuery accordion widget- and I'm definitely missing something.  The widget [here](http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/accordion/default.html) looks great.  But if I grab that EXACT html and create a stand alone page then open it in IE or Chrome it looks terrible.  No rounded corners, the little drop down arrows are halfway down the page and not on the headers... I just want to create an accordion widget that looks exactly like the example.

What am I missing here, and where is the CSS coming from that styles the accordion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're missing is [a ton of CSS](http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/style.css). That's what's rounding the corners, providing the gradients, and placing the arrows.

Comment: That's not what I consider a ton of CSS in the link you have- far from it.  I also updated that link to that in my page to http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/style.css which changes the font size and type but nothing else.  I DO agree that there is a ton of CSS coming from somewhere... but where?

Comment: I think I found it- I was missing the CSS from here:http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css and there are also a load of images it looks like that give it the look and feel... will play with that

Comment: Haha!  Well you were right- I was missing a ton- just not from that source.  I got it working- minus the images but it still looks good.  Cheers.